# install application data from SD card of emulator to android device

Tags: android, sd-card

I have a media player application, where videos are saved in SDcard image of emulator. Now, i want to run same application on android device.

How to transfer video from SDcard image to device memory?

***what are the changes need to be made for my program...***

**Code:**

```
  final String MEDIA_PATH = new String("/sdcard/");
  //path of sdcard image on emulaotr

public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getPlayList()
    {
        File home = new File(MEDIA_PATH);

        if (home.listFiles(new FileExtensionFilter()).length > 0) 
        {
            for (File file : home.listFiles(new FileExtensionFilter())) 
            {
                HashMap<String, String> song = new HashMap<String,String>();
                song.put("songTitle", file.getName().substring(0, (file.getName().length() - 4)));
                song.put("songPath", file.getPath());

                // Adding each song to SongList
                songsList.add(song);
            }
        }

        return songsList;
    }


    class FileExtensionFilter implements FilenameFilter
    {
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name) 
        {
            return (name.endsWith(".mp3") || name.endsWith(".MP3") || name.endsWith(".mp4") || name.endsWith(".MP4"));
        }
    }
```

Comment: String MEDIA_PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

Comment: thank u so much  user2045570 ..But where to add videos in android device(device location)

Comment: `Environment.getDataDirectory()` - android device, data directory.